# Triggering the right event for lazy loading of images on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lazy-loading

I am considering using HtmlUnit / PhantomJS tools to programmatically read the complete pinterest.com webpage (eg. http://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=nivea). The images are lazily loaded into the web page as the browser window approaches the end of the page. I cannot figure out what lazy loading technique is used on that page, ie. what events do I need to fire or what functions to call by using the aforementioned tools to load the complete page (all images).
Thanks

Comment: I dont understand your problem.You are facing problem to retrieve the data due to lazy loading of image or you want to know how the lazy loading of image is done in this page ??

Comment: My primary aim is the retrieval for which I have to trigger the proper javascript code on that page.

Comment: So you can trigger the javascript code through HTMLUNIT with help of JS function.

Comment: What javascript code exactly? :)

Comment: htmlPage.executeJavaScript(JS Function);

Comment: My main problem from the beginning is that I don't know which JS function exactly to call. I cannot find it out from the pinterest's code

Comment: You need to check dear.This can't b help by someone online.